# Socket exception in sending HTTP request without Connection header using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, httprequest

When I use the following code to send HTTP GET request using sockets in C#

```
    IPEndPoint RHost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 80);
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect(RHost);
    String req = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: awebsite.com\r\n\r\n";

    socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req), SocketFlags.None);
    int bytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    do
    {
        bytes = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        result.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
    }
    while (bytes > 0);
```

I get

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host'

and when I add `Connection: Close` header to the request, it is working without any problem.
But using Repeater tool in the Burp Suite I am able to send and receive a response from the server without setting  `Connection: Close` header.

**Notes:**

- I have to use socket.
- I am facing this problem just with few websites, not every website

Comment: Did you try to set a timeout? For example `socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a HTTP/1.1 request. Without an explicit `Connection: close` there is an implicit `Connection: keep-alive` with HTTP/1.1 (different to HTTP/1.0). This means that the server might wait for new requests within the same TCP connection after the response is done and close the connection sometimes later if no new requests arrive. This later close might be done with a RST which results in the error you see.

But, your code expects the server to behave differently: it expects that the server closes the connection once the request is done and not to wait for more requests and not to close the idle connection with RST.

To fix this you have either to adapt your request so that the server behavior matches your expectations or to adjust the expectations.
The first can be done by either explicitly adding `Connection: close` header or by simply using HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1. The latter one is recommended because this also results in simpler responses (no chunked response).
If you instead want to adjust your expectations you have to properly parse the servers response: first read the header, then check for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or `Content-length` and then read the response body based on what these headers say. For details see [the HTTP standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: Thanks, I tested my code with HTTP/1.0 and its working without problem, however, I'm not allowed to manipulate the request (changing HTTP version or adding/removing headers). So I guess I have to check response headers for Transfer-Encoding: chunked or Content-length, but wondering if it is guaranteed that response has one of these headers!?

Comment: @HadiRj: if you implement a protocol it is highly recommended that you get familiar with the standard, i.e. [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) in this case. From this you will see that there are three ways to specify where a response ends: by chunked encoding, by content-length and if none of these is given by connection close.